No funciona funcion en tk
Estoy aprendiendo tkinter, pero al tratar de hacer un programa no me funciona una función. El programa tiene un botón que cuenta tus clicks, y yo he creado una función para que a los 10 clicks te sume un click, pero por alguna razón no funciona.
Este es el código:
from tkinter import *
import time
import pyautogui



raiz=Tk()

raiz.attributes('-fullscreen',True)

raiz.title("Cliker")

raiz.resizable(0,0)

raiz.config(bg="#5e5d5d")

Frame=Frame(raiz, width=500, height=350, bg="#383838")
Frame.pack()

Clicks=StringVar()
Click=0

def mas_un_click():
        global Click
        Click=Click+1
        Clicks.set(Click)
        print(Click)

    Boton=Button(Frame, text="Click", width=5, height=2, cursor="plus",command=mas_un_click, font=("Bauhaus 93",10))
    Boton.place(x=215, y=100)
    Boton.config(bd=15, bg="grey")
    
    LabelClicks=Label(Frame, textvariable=Clicks, width=10, height=1, bg="#b8b3b2", relief="ridge", bd=10, cursor="none", font=("Rockwell Extra Bold",8))
    LabelClicks.pack()
    LabelClicks.place(x=198.26, y=180)
    
    Titulo=Label(Frame, text="Clicker", bg="#383838", font=("Algerian",30))
    Titulo.pack()
    Titulo.place(x=180, y=10)
    
    Label_mas_un_click=Label(Frame, text="10 clicks    1 clik al segundo", bg="#FFFFFF", font=("Berlin Sans FB Demi",10))
    Label_mas_un_click.pack()
    Label_mas_un_click.place(x=340, y=50)
    
    if Click>10:
        Frame.after(1000)
        mas_un_click()
    
    def salir():
        pyautogui.hotkey("alt", "F4")
    
    Boton_exit=Button(Frame, text="exit", font=("Berlin Sans FB Demi",10), command=salir)
    Boton_exit.pack()
    Boton_exit.place(x=0, y=10)
    
    
    
    raiz.mainloop()

No entiendo porque cuando llego a más de diez clicks no se suma uno cada segundo.

Estás seguro de que la indentación está correcta??? Yo lo veo un poco raro... has copiado bien el código? En python la indentación es muy importante

Si tienes el bloque:
if Click>10:
    Frame.after(1000)
    mas_un_click()

a nivel global, se ejecutará una sola vez al ejecutar el script y el condicional nunca se cumplirá por tanto, ya que Clicks será 0.
La condición debe introducirse en la propia callback mas_un_click, de forma que se empiece a llamar a si misma cada segundo cuando los clicks sean 10 o más.
Ten en cuenta que para ejecutar una función pasado x tiempo sin bloquear la interfaz debes usar after de la siguiente forma:
tk_widget.after(tiempo_de_espera_en ms, callback_a_ejecutar)

Por cierto, no hay razón para usar dos gestores de geometría a la vez sobre el mismo widget, usa pack, grid o place para posicionar el widget pero no varios.
Puedes hacer algo como:
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui


raiz = tk.Tk()
raiz.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
raiz.title("Cliker")
raiz.resizable(0, 0)
raiz.config(bg="#5e5d5d")

frame = tk.Frame(raiz, width=500, height=350, bg="#383838")
frame.pack()

clicks = tk.IntVar(frame, 0)

def mas_un_click(auto=False):
    if (n_clicks := clicks.get()) == 9 or auto:
        frame.after(1000, lambda: mas_un_click(auto=True))
    clicks.set(n_clicks + 1)

boton = tk.Button(
    frame, text="Click", width=5, height=2, cursor="plus",
    command=mas_un_click, font=("Bauhaus 93", 10),
    bd=15, bg="grey"
)
boton.place(x=215, y=100)

label_clicks = tk.Label(
    frame, textvariable=clicks, width=10, height=1, bg="#b8b3b2",
    relief="ridge", bd=10, cursor="none", font=("Rockwell Extra Bold", 8)
)

label_clicks.place(x=198.26, y=180)

titulo = tk.Label(frame, text="Clicker", bg="#383838", font=("Algerian", 30))
titulo.place(x=180, y=10)

label_mas_un_click = tk.Label(
    frame, text="10 clicks    1 clik al segundo",
    bg="#FFFFFF", font=("Berlin Sans FB Demi", 10)
)
label_mas_un_click.pack()
label_mas_un_click.place(x=340, y=50)

def salir():
    pyautogui.hotkey("alt", "F4")

boton_exit = tk.Button(
    frame, text="exit", font=("Berlin Sans FB Demi", 10), command=salir
)
boton_exit.pack()
boton_exit.place(x=0, y=10)
raiz.mainloop()

Dos recomendaciones:

Evita el uso de from modulo import *, en general es una mala práctica, hace el código menos legible, puebla el espacio de nombres actual sin necesidad y puede ocasionar colisiones de nombres indeseados y los consecuentes errores, a veces difíciles de detectar o incluso silentes. En el caso de tkinter lo veras importado así en muchos tutoriales e incluso ejemplos de la documentación, pero no deja de ser una mala práctica.

Considera seguir las recomendaciones de estilo de PEP-8, son solo convenciones pero hacen tu código más legible para otros desarrolladores de Python.



Nota
Si estás usando pyautogui solo para salir de la app, no lo hagas, es más simple y apropiado:
def salir():
    raiz.destroy()

o directamente:
boton_exit = tk.Button(
    frame, text="exit", font=("Berlin Sans FB Demi", 10), command=raiz.destroy
)


Me ayudaste a muchas cosas, gracias.

Cuidado con los nombres de las variables. minúscula para las variables, Mayúscula+minúsculas para clases y todo MAYÚSCULAS para constantes (por ejemplo WIDTH o HEIGHT). También evita que sean demasiado largas y, sobre todo, NUNCA llames a una variable de la misma manera que una clase o función. Frame=Frame(...) nos hace daño a los ojos a cualquier programador.
Creo que tu código no está bien copiado pero supongo que tu error está en que tienes puesto que tu variable Clicks incrementará cada vez que se clique, a partir de los 10 primeros clicks - if Click>10:.... Lo que hay que hacer es incrementarlo solo cada 10 clicks, por lo tanto, en vez de > hay que utilizar el símbolo % que calcula el resto de la división y si da 0 significa que Click es divisible entre 10.
Así quedaría tu código una vez cambiadas las variables y arreglado el problema - he quitado el frame.after(1000) que solo hacía que el programa fuera más lento.
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui


raiz=Tk()

raiz.attributes('-fullscreen',True)

raiz.title("Cliker")

raiz.resizable(0,0)

raiz.config(bg="#5e5d5d")

frame=Frame(raiz, width=500, height=350, bg="#383838")
frame.pack()

clicks=IntVar()  # La variable es de tipo int, no str --> utilizamos IntVar
counter=0

def mas_un_click(clicks: IntVar):
    global counter
    counter+=1
    if counter%10==0:  # Cada 10 clicks incrementamos la variable "clicks" en 1
        clicks.set(clicks.get() + 1)
    print(counter)

boton=Button(frame, text="Click", width=5, height=2, cursor="plus",command=lambda: mas_un_click(clicks), font=("Bauhaus 93",10))
boton.place(x=215, y=100)
boton.config(bd=15, bg="grey")

labelClicks=Label(frame, textvariable=clicks, width=10, height=1, bg="#b8b3b2", relief="ridge", bd=10, cursor="none", font=("Rockwell Extra Bold",8))
labelClicks.pack()
labelClicks.place(x=198.26, y=180)

titulo=Label(frame, text="Clicker", bg="#383838", font=("Algerian",30))
titulo.pack()
titulo.place(x=180, y=10)

label_masClick=Label(frame, text="10 clicks    1 clik al segundo", bg="#FFFFFF", font=("Berlin Sans FB Demi",10))
label_masClick.pack()
label_masClick.place(x=340, y=50)

def salir():
    pyautogui.hotkey("alt", "F4")

boton_exit=Button(frame, text="exit", font=("Berlin Sans FB Demi",10), command=salir)
boton_exit.pack()
boton_exit.place(x=0, y=10)

raiz.mainloop()


Gracias pero no quiero que cada diez clicks se sume un click, lo que quiero es que una vez que lleges a diez clicks se sume un click cada segundo

from tkinter import *
import time, pyautogui

raiz = Tk()

raiz.title("Cliker")
raiz.resizable(0, 0)
raiz.config(bg="#5e5d5d")
Frame = Frame(raiz, width=500, height=350, bg="#383838")
Frame.pack()

Clicks = StringVar()
Click = 0

def mas_un_click():
 global Click
 Click += 1
 Clicks.set(Click)

def verificar_clicks():
 global Click
 if Click >= 10:
  print(Click)
  Click += 1
  Clicks.set(Click)
 raiz.after(1000, verificar_clicks)

Boton = Button(Frame, text="Click", width=5, height=2, cursor="plus", command=mas_un_click, font=("Bauhaus 93", 10))
Boton.place(x=215, y=100)
Boton.config(bd=15, bg="grey")

LabelClicks = Label(Frame, textvariable=Clicks, width=10, height=1, bg="#b8b3b2", relief="ridge", bd=10, cursor="none", font=("Rockwell Extra Bold", 8))
LabelClicks.pack()
LabelClicks.place(x=198.26, y=180)

Titulo = Label(Frame, text="Clicker", bg="#383838", font=("Algerian", 30))
Titulo.pack()
Titulo.place(x=180, y=10)

Label_mas_un_click = Label(Frame, text="10 clicks    1 clik al segundo", bg="#FFFFFF", font=("Berlin Sans FB Demi", 10))
Label_mas_un_click.pack()
Label_mas_un_click.place(x=340, y=50)

def salir():
 pyautogui.hotkey("alt", "F4")

Boton_exit = Button(Frame, text="exit", font=("Berlin Sans FB Demi", 10), command=salir)
Boton_exit.pack()
Boton_exit.place(x=0, y=10)
verificar_clicks()
raiz.mainloop()


¿Cómo responde este código a la pregunta? Lee [answer] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta.

Hola, gracias por tu contribución, la pregunta ya tiene una respuesta, la revisaste?
